# grep words from commented file

Tags: awk, grep

I want to grep a particular command/word say `int` from a file. 
But I want to eliminate all those lines which are commented.
(I want to ignore if int is after `#` ).

My file content :

```
int a
def
abc int
adbc asdfj #int
abc # int
# int abc
abc int #
int # abc
```

I want output as :

```
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

I tried using `grep -e "int" | grep -v -e "#"` .
But problem is `int # abc` is also getting eliminated.

Comment: If `integer` but not standalone `int` appeared on the line, would you want that line output or not?

Comment: @EdMorton: No I dont want that. I want lines containing word 'int'

Comment: And what about lines like `foo int # bar int` - should that line be printed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some deleted answers with this valid single-regex answer: `grep '^[^#]*\<int\>'`

```
grep '^[^#]*\<int\>' <<END
int a
def
abc int
adbc asdfj #int
abc # int
abc int #
int # abc
print abc  # int -- should not see this line
END
```

```
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

Do you have `int` on both sides of the `#`? What should you do in that case?

```
$ echo "int foo # int bar" | grep '^[^#]*\<int\>'
int foo # int bar
```

---

To see if "int" is used in the file, use grep's `-q` option:

```
if grep -q '^[^#]*\<int\>' file; then 
    echo "I have an 'int'"
else
    echo "No int here"
fi
```

To pass the word as a parameter, you need double quotes, and escape the backslashes:

```
type="int"
if grep -q "^[^#]*\\<$type\\>"; then ...
```

Comment: Anchored at the start of the line (`^`), find zero or more characters that are not a hash (`[^#]*`) followed by the stand-alone word "int" (`\<int\>` -- `\<` is a "start of word" marker, `\>` is "end of word")

Comment: What I need is to simply check whether the word "int" is used in the file or not. I also need to ensure that it should not be used in comment, usage should be actual. That is my exact need. I am grepping it, after that if [ $i -eq 0] then I will know that it has been used.so int foo # int bar should give output as actual usage

Comment: actually int will be stored in a variable. "i". int was just for example

Comment: @gelnn jackman: I used this grep -w "^[^#]*$i". It worked fine for me. Why did you change the answer

Comment: But here I am getting another problem. Despite of writing -w it is considering fint as match

Comment: @PratikKumar, that's why I changed the answer. I used word boundaries around "int" specifically.

Comment: As it stands right now, this is the only answer that will match "int" but not "fint"

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/int/ && !/#.*int/' file
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

This will get all line that contains `int` but ignore if `int` comes after `#` (comment)

Comment: This will remove if int is after any comment, i know it works for OPs sample file but say he had 'int # abc int`. It would remove that line as well, not sure if OP cares about that but it is something to think about

Comment: If I use this command, will it work in all cases ?
grep "int" file | grep -v -e "#.*int"

Comment: @Jidder That is true.  It will remove line like `data to read # I do use int to make this to work`. And this is correct when you read OPs comment  `(I want to ignore if int is after #)`. Not saying anything about start of line, nor about word between `#` and `int`

Comment: I know that OP did not mention it could be before and after the `#`, but i'm not sure if it has just been overlooked by OP. In any case your answer answers OPs question perfectly for what was asked so it was just a thought :)

Comment: @PratikKumar that example contains int ?

Comment: @PratikKumar See my updated answer.  It handles the need of `int` in the line.

Answer (score 0):

And the one through sed,

```
$ sed '/#.*int/d' file
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

It just deletes the line in which the string `int` is just after to `#` symbol.

Comment: If I use this command, will it work in all cases ?
grep "int" file | grep -v -e "#.*int"

Comment: That will print lines where `int` does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `perl`? if so it's a piece of cake:

```
perl -ne '/int/ && !/#(.*?)int/ && print' file 
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

Another alternative is to use -P for grep:

```
grep -Pv '#.*?int' file | grep int
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

If you want to ignore all comments it can be done with `sed` :

```
grep -Pv '#.*?int' file | grep int | sed -re 's/#.*//g'
int a
abc int
abc int 
int
```

Using variable instead of "int":

```
i="int"; grep -Pv "#.*?$i" file | grep "$i"
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

Comment: @PratikKumar `perl` is a program used in `bash` as same as `awk` `sed` and `grep`

Comment: @PratikKumar does your grep support `-P`?

Comment: @Tiago yes it supports -P. It is coming in grep --help

Comment: @PratikKumar I added to my answer an alternative to Perl using only grep :)

Comment: In my case int is stored in a variable 'i' & need to match complete word . So can I use this : grep -Pv "#.*?$i" a | grep -w "$i"  and in the next line check "$?" to know whether match is found or not.  One more thing . If line is int #int . I want it to be detected which is not happening here.

Comment: @PratikKumar Look at my answer for your last point of `int #int`

Comment: @Jidder : I have tried using that but I always get an error "index: Event not Found"

Comment: @PratikKumar would you like to get rid of '# abc' after int? If so you could use `sed` for that. If not I don't understand what you want.

Comment: What I need is to simply check whether the word "int" is used in the file or not. I also need to ensure that it should not be used in comment, usage should be actual. That is my exact need.
I am grepping it, after that if [ $i -eq 0] then I will know that it has been used. My problem is if line is like int # abc , it should say yes actual usage. But if # int abc. It should not say no usage

Comment: If int fasdf # int , it should still say actual usage. 
Here I was taking int as an example, Actually it will be stored in a variable. I am implementing in bash

Comment: @PratikKumar what is the full error including line number, there is no reason it shouldnt work, also are you using it from the command line or in a script ?

Comment: @PratikKumar what you asked in you question has been correctly answered many times in this page. I believe you struggling with something else. Can you share a pastebin with what are you trying to do and what errors you're getting?

Comment: I was using from command line. Now when I used from bash script .It worked. Please tell me how I will substitute variable in place of int because this is not giving proper output. I just want to know whether match has been found or not.                                     awk '/$i/ && (index($0,"$i") < index($0,"#") || !index($0,"#"))' file

Comment: @PratikKumar It's on my answer now.

Comment: @PratikKumar `awk '/$i/ && (index($0,"$i") < index($0,"#") || !index($0,"#"))' file` should be `awk '/i/ && (index($0,i) < index($0,"#") || !index($0,"#"))' i=$i file` , that's how you pass variable to awk.

Comment: @Tiago : i="int"; grep -Pv "#.*?$i" file | grep "$i" This command is ignoring int # int, which I dont want because int has been actually used

Comment: @Tiago considering your answer now contains my answer i may as well delete mine :(

Comment: @Tiago deleted my comment by accident, you may want to use -v to pass the variable as it currently matches any line with `i` `n` or `t` in that order on it.E.g add `init` to a line and it will match

Comment: @Tiago sorry to keep bothering but i was wrong, i think its actually to do with the fact that you are only searching for i in the '/i/' not the variable

Comment: Last one :) It should be `i=int; awk '/'$i'/ && (index($0,i) < index($0,"#") || !index($0,"#"))' i="$i" file`

Comment: @Jidder Look at awk args `i=$i file` `i=$i` has the same effect of `-v i=$i`

Comment: I know , i didnt see that at first, as i said in a previous comment that is not the problem. But what i was saying, is that the `i` in `/i/` is being taken as a literal i, not what is contained in the variable.

Comment: To match against a variable, you have to use `$0 ~ i`

Comment: @glennjackman jidder, you're right... I just added that command to show how to pass variable to awk, I will delete that part. BTW does anybody know what pratikkumar wants?

Comment: @Jotne - wrt `perl is a program used in bash as same as awk sed and grep`, no it is not. awk, sed, and grep come with every UNIX installation while perl does not. I frequently use machines where perl is not installed and I don't have permission to install it.

Comment: @EdMorton What I ment was that `perl` is a program that can be used in linux system if its installed. The same to say with the other.  It need to be installed to work of course :)  (not all has `awk`, but I have not seen any without `sed`)

Comment: If it has sed, it has awk. In 30+ years of programming on UNIX systems I've never seen a system without both (though sometimes it's been just old, broken awk (shudder!). I just looked up the POSIX standard (http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/) and when you search for sed and awk you get their definitions but when you search for perl you get `Sorry, no match. Try a Word Search`.

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT be what you want, using GNU awk for word boundaries:

```
$ awk -F'#' '$1~/\<int\>/' file
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

depending on what you want to do if `int` appears both before and after the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/abc int/ || /^int/' file
int a
abc int
abc int #
int # abc
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `abc` isn't meant to be hard coded.